# How to refresh an image copy in an html page according to the clicked image in another html page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I make online shop. 
I have two html pages: p1.html and p2.html. p1.html has many images with img tag. Every img tag links to its zoomed copy in p2.html page. p2.html has the only img tag with description and zooming function (lens effect). When clicking any image a user is redirected to its zoomed copy in p2.html page. But I can not refresh image in p2.html according to the clicked image in p1.html. I can not access image in p2.html with code like this (I use jQuery):

p1.html:

```
<div><a href="p2.html"><img src="image_1.png"></a></div>
<script>
$("img").click(function(){        
  var x = $(this).attr("src");
  $("#itemimage").attr("src", x); });

</script>
```

p2.html:

```
<div class="image-details"><img id="itemimage" src="image_x.png"></div>
```

Comment: First you have not closing > for first div in first page. Second, why you need p2? What if you place all image details on p1 also and have them hidden and when clicked jQuery just popup and display that image with id will be easy for you to code by keeping in one page.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at Local Storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: The script you have in p1.html doesn't run on p2.html. Not sure why you'd redirect to show an image, but if you have to, you could send the image name as a query string in the redirection URL and get it from there. Using localstorage would help too, and you could even try to store the image as base64 in p1.html and load it in p2.html

Comment: Just ad target _new to the link and the image will always open in a new page, no html needed.

Comment: @Mohsin: If you mean the modal box I need to redirect a user to exactly another html page. No popup.

Comment: @LuisEgan: May be I need to change context with jQuery to solve this problem? Then how to make it?

Comment: it wouldn't work if you load a new .HTML it doesn't have anything from the previous one, it's a new file, with new JS.